# Ember.js computed property with dependency on array property's element

Tags: ember.js

I want to have a computed property in a class, that depends on a property (array of strings) of the same class. I want this computed property to depend on a particular element of the array only.

Actually, I would not mind if it depends on all elements of the array either.

I have the ember defined like so:

```
var UpdateController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    PANE_1:     0,
    PANE_2:     1,
    PANE_3:     2,

    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('paneClass', ["center", "right", "right"]);
    },

    channelsPaneClass: function() {
         return this.get('paneClass')[this.get('PANE_1')];
    }.property('paneClass.@each'),
}
```

This computed property is being used in a template like so:

```
<div {{bind-attr class=":sf-seg-pane channelsPaneClass"}}></div>
```

This outputs the following html:

```
<div class="sf-seg-pane center"></div>
```

So far, so good. However, if I now change the value of element `paneClass[PANE_1]`, like so:

```
this.get('paneClass')[this.get('PANE_1')] = "xxx";
```

I was expecting the html to change into:

```
<div class="sf-seg-pane xxx"></div>
```

But it doesn't.

What else have I tried:

1. I've tried specifying the property dependency like `.property('paneClass')`.
2. I've tried using `{{bind-attr class=":sf-seg-pane paneClass[0]"}}` in the template.
3. I've seen [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/), which outlines a way to get it done when our array is an array of objects. I do not see any example for an array of primitive data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use `paneClass.[]` instead of `paneClass.@each` because `paneClass.@each` is intended to observe some property from an object in the array. Also add the `PANE_1` in the `property` since this is a dependent key.

```
var UpdateController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    PANE_1:     0,
    PANE_2:     1,
    PANE_3:     2,
    init: function() {
        this._super();
        this.set('paneClass', ["center", "right", "right"]);
    },
    channelsPaneClass: function() {
         return this.get('paneClass')[this.get('pane1')];
    }.property('paneClass.[]', 'PANE_1'),
}
```

And to notify the observers that the array changed you need to use `array.insertAt(index, content)` instead of `array[index] = content`. In your case:

```
this.get('paneClass').insertAt(this.get('PANE_1'), "xxx");
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for your time. If you don't mind, is this documented somewhere. I've been googling for hours. Finally, I used a workaround involving objects as outlined here: http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

Comment: You're welcome. About the `insertAt` the only place that I know is the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_insertAt).

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `paneClass.[]` syntax.

Comment: No problem. [This](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__each) is the docs of @each

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a setter, you are essentially changing the data out from under ember

Comment: How do I use a setter for an array element? If it was an object, I'd use this.set('paneClass', "xxx"). But `paneClass` is an array and I want to set it's 0'th element to "xxx".